# Passing parameters in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have a sharedClient which requests a URL

```
#define BASE_URL @"http://myurl.com"

+ (id)sharedClient {
static MyClient *__instance;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    NSURL *baseUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:BASE_URL];
    __instance = [[MyClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseUrl];
});
    return __instance;
}
```

I then call this in a view controller when a button is pressed

```
id params = @{
              @"username": self.usernameField.text,
              @"password": self.passwordField.text
              };

[[MyClient sharedClient]getPath:@"/users/current.json"
                           parameters:params
                              success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                  NSString *authToken = [responseObject objectForKey:@"api_key"];
                                  [self.credentialStore setAuthToken:authToken];

                                  [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

                                  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
                              } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                  NSLog(@"%ld", (long)operation.response.statusCode);
                                  if (operation.response.statusCode == 500) {
                                      [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Something went wrong!"];
                                  } else {
                                      NSData *jsonData = [operation.responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                      NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                                                           options:0
                                                                                             error:nil];
                                      NSString *errorMessage = [json objectForKey:@"error"];
                                      [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:errorMessage];
                                  }
                              }];
```

This code works correctly, but my issue is the API I am trying to access is a little odd. You have to pass the username and password in before the url. Like this

`http://username:password@myurl.com`

How would I go about passing the params in before the http of the URL?

Comment: As far as I know, that is a standard (but unsafe) mechanism to transmit username and password with a URL.  `[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://username:password@myurl.com"]` should simply work.

Comment: How would I make the username and password dynamic? In other words I would I pass in the username and password?

Comment: If you are targeting iOS 7 and later, NSURLComponents is the way to go.

Comment: @FilipRadelic I am targeting iOS7 and above, have you got an example of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSURLComponents *urlComponents = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:BASE_URL];
urlComponents.user = @"user";
urlComponents.password = @"pass";
NSURL *url = urlComponents.URL;
```

Then just use `url` to init your client.

Answer (score 1):

The "odd" form is perfectly valid and has been with HTTP as long as I can think, but it's unsafe when used with HTTP (but is safe when used with HTTPS, where the request is sent over an encrypted connection).

Simply construct the URL like this with every request:

```
static NSString * const kBaseScheme = @"http"
static NSString * const kBaseHostAndPath = @"myurl.com/mypath"

...

NSString *urlString;
if ([username length] > 0 && [password length] > 0) {
    urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@://%@:%@@%@", kBaseScheme, username, password, kBaseHostAndPath];
} else {
    urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@://%@", kBaseScheme, kBaseHostAndPath];
}
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
```

You can also "deconstruct" an existing `NSURL` and then "reconstruct" the URL, if you prefer that (you would do this with the instance variable where you've stored your URL of your `[[MyClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseUrl];` call; but you could also do an initializer like `initWithScheme:kBaseScheme hostAndPath:kBaseHostAndPath]` and save those in two instance variables).

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@://%@:%@@%@%@", [baseURL scheme], username, password, [baseURL host], [baseURL path]];
```

See the also [NSURL documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) about the various fields.

Comment: You were faster :-) - One probably should escape user name and password with stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, just one quick question: How would I pass the username and password to the singleton class?

Comment: a singleton object is nothing different than an object. use ivars.

Comment: @joshuahornby10: As vikingosegundo said, just use instance variables. See my updated answer. You can either use the fields of your already existing `baseUrl`, or you split it up into two fields.

Comment: Oh, and @MartinR is absolutely right: you need to escape username and password! Imagine someone having the password `a@foo.com/`, it would redirect your request if you didn't escape it.